# Cannot access network location from some softwares

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, disk

I have this strange problem : I work with windows 7 and I have some network location disks. One of them is K:

From sqldeveloper, I cannot see those disks and now connecting to mysql with command line and trying to reach some files on those disks using "source" : there is an error saying that the file is not found as it searches on C: and not on K:, like it does not see it.

Do you have any idea what is going on ?

Note : I am on a virtual machine. (it used to work good when I was not on the VM but on the computer itself)

Comment: Are you running sqldeverloper as admin? Network shares don't get shared automatically under different user contexts.

Comment: I found it finally and you are on the good tracks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks to this article :

http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/

So the solution is just to add a key in the regedit : EnableLinkedConnections with value 1